# Rearrange divs randomly using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, random, shuffle

I've got a 3x3 grid layout using divs which upon clicking a button I need the divs to rearrange randomly. The following link illustrates an idea of what I need to create.

[image]

I don't need help with the HTML layout nor CSS design of the assignment per-se, but rather how to create the `onclick` function using native Javascript or jQuery in order for the "shuffle" and "sort" buttons to work. If possible, preferably Jquery, as I am more comfortable with its syntax.

I thank all in advance for help and support. Any useful links for me to do my own research is highly appreciated.

I am not looking for others to per say do my work for me, although solutions are highly appreciated, but perhaps guide me in a pseudo-code sort of way.

Comment: jQuery has very good documentation. Here's how to use the `click()` handler: http://api.jquery.com/click. Here's the documentation for the native JS way of attaching a click handler: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: You can use http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ for shuffle effects.

Comment: This looks like it is some kind of test? Should you be able to do this on your own? I see you removed the part mentioning it was a test from the image now...

Comment: @ComputerLocus I did indeed as I don't know the exact rules of conduct here.
I just need some help in the pseudocode or perhaps what selectors I should use.
I have an idea using arrays, but not sure if that's the most efficient way.

Comment: @SC87 But is this for some kind of job application? If you are unable to do this kind of work should you be going forward with such a task?

Comment: @SC87 and... the docs linked above aren't helping? Both provide clear examples.

Comment: What i would do is create a multidimensional array of your grid. Ex: [[1,1], [1,2], ...]. Then randomly select a value from that array and move one div there. Make sure to remove that value from the array so it can't be chosen again. Repeat this for the remaining divs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Randomizing the order of divs on page load with jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123252/randomizing-the-order-of-divs-on-page-load-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different algorithms that you can use to "shuffle" a list of items. However, one of my favorite methods is the following because it is very concise.

**General Shuffle Algorithm:**

1. Find a list of items to rearrange.
2. Remove a random element from the items to rearrange
3. Insert the element into a new list
4. Repeat steps 1-3 until there are no more items left in the original list

**Code Example**

Here is a function that should do the trick:

```
$container = $("#container");
$divList = $("div");

$("#shuffle").on("click", function(){
  //copy and remove all divs
  $divCopy = $divList.clone(true);
  $("div").remove();

  while($divCopy.length > 0){
    //chose random index of div array
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * $divList.length);

    $container.append($divCopy.splice(randomIndex, 1));
  }
});
```

There is a full working version at https://jsfiddle.net/oruq1qou/

If you are interested in looking for other methods of solving this problem, I would recommend doing some reading on the different types of shuffle algorithms around.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
This is exactly what I needed to accomplish.  However, is it ok if I ask you to give me insight as to your mental process to analyze and figure out the task?  
Thank you.

Comment: @SC87 Hey, glad it works for you. I tried to outline the more generalized algorithm of the problem so that hopefully you can get a better sense of how I thought about it.

Comment: Looking through it right now.
I honestly appreciate your help and patience.

Comment: @SC87 Not a problem, let me know if you need more explanation